# Does Euler Third Substitution gives different answers?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

In the book "Special Techniques for Solving Integrals: Examples and Problems" by Khristo N. Boyadzhiev, I am given the integral $$F(x)= \int \frac{dx}{(x+3)\sqrt{3x-x^2 -2}}$$ as an example.

The example is as such,

\begin{align} 
\sqrt{-x^2+3x-2} &= t(x-1)\\
\implies x &= \frac{t^2 +2}{t^2 +1} \\
\implies \frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{-2t}{(t^2 +1)^2} \\
\therefore F(x) &= \int \frac{dx}{(x+3)\sqrt{3x-x^2 -2}} \\
&= \int \frac{-2}{4t^2 +5} dt \\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\arctan{\frac{2t}{\sqrt5}} +c \\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\arctan{\frac{2\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt{5(x-1)}}} +c
\end{align}

Then, the author said that setting $\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-2)} = t(x-2)$ would work too.

This would yield

$$x = \frac{2t^2 +1}{t^2 +1}, \quad \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{2t}{(t^2 +1)^2}$$

So,

\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int \frac{dx}{(x+3)\sqrt{3x-x^2 -2}} \\
&= \int -\frac{t^2 +1 }{t(5t^2 +4)} (t^2 +1) \frac{2t}{(t^2 +1)^2} dt \\
&= \int \frac{-2}{5t^2 +4} dt \\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\arctan{\frac{t\sqrt5}{2}} +c \\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{5(1-x)}}{2\sqrt{x-2}}} +c
\end{align}

I checked on my gc, differentiating both answers, would yield different curves. However, the curves are the negative of each other. Initially I thought I miss a $-1$ somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x\in(1,2)$, otherwise the number inside the square root is negative. In your second case,
\begin{align*}
t&=\frac{\overbrace{\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-2)}}^{\text{positive}}}{\underbrace{x-2}_\text{negative}}
=\frac{\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-2)}}{-\sqrt{(x-2)^2}}
=-\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{2-x}},
\end{align*}
you miss a $-1$ here.

Comment: May I ask then, For the first subst. of "$\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-2)} = t(x-1)$, $t=\frac{\sqrt{-(x-1)(x-2)}}{x-1}$, since $x\in(1,2)$, $x-1$ is positive and $-(x-1)(x-2)$ is also positive, so $t = \sqrt{-\frac{x-2}{x-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{2-x}{x-1}} $. There's no need to make a $(-1)$ appear since $x-1$ is positive and $-(x-1)(x-2)$ is also positive

Comment: @ArcNeoepi You are right. :)